# Is Microsoft ASP.NET Dynamic Data website a platform i can trust for making websites admin areas?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web, dynamic-data

Did you used Dynamic websites before? you see its a good way for making fast admin areas for our websites?

Is it easy to customize?
Is it easy for the end user to manipulate?

I am thinking to use it with a client and didn't use before, can you advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I've used it.

Fundamentally if what you want to do is maintain tables as tables then its pretty much a yes across the board. Starting with a set of Linq classes (Linq to SQL or Linq to Entities) you get a mostly useable set of edit pages immediately.

You can then add custom field handling, pages, sort orders, most things you'd want.

Customisation is straightforward and can be developed over time - more importantly you change the database schema and keep your customisations intact.

Not perfect, but you get a *huge* amount of functionality for very little code.

Comment: I agree. I also setup the admin portion of a site using dynamic data and it worked well. The only problem is the documentation that I have found lacking, but that may be because it is a new product.